# <img align="center" not working HTML

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

Img Align centre or center not working on HTML website kodeum.co.uk. The error is on line 232

```
    <div class="container mt">
    <div class="row clients centered">
      <p class="mb">Some clients that I had the pleasure to working for.</p>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <img align="centre" src="assets/img/coding-kids.png" alt="Coding Kids">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <img src="assets/img/flydan.png" alt="flyDan">
      </div>
    </div><!--/row-->
  </div><!--/container-->
</div><!--/.G-->
```

Can Anyone Help?

Harry

Comment: @LGSon I Tried Both. Still No Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you just misspelled center 
But you may have better results doing it within the style of the div anyways
Try this, Assuming the width of your png is 200px

```
<div class="col-sm-2" style="width: 200px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <img src="assets/img/coding-kids.png" alt="Coding Kids">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It Worked. Will Accept Your Answer In 8 Mins. (Won't Let Me Do It Yet)!!